# How I can use "/%s" function into shiny r

Tags: html, r, shiny

I can't open and show html file into shiny code in r

I'm trying make it by R programm:

**ui.R**

```
tabItem(tabName = "ndvi",
  fluidPage(tags$style(type = "text/css", "#map{height: 800px !important;}"),
  fluidRow(
    column(2, 
      dateInput("date1", 
                label = "DATE",
                value = "2018-08-07")
    )
  ),

  fluidRow(
    htmlOutput("frame1")
```

**server.R**

```
 framePath <- reactive({
return(sprintf("http://10.0.6.179:5656/WEB_NKR/ndvi_shape_files/agro_priishimski//%s_agro_priishimski.html", input$date1))

  })  

  output$frame1 <- renderUI({
    tags$iframe(seamless="seamless", src=framePath(), height=800, width=1650)
  })
```

I must take in the result:
[image]

Comment: There should be only one slash here: `agro_priishimski//%s_agro_priishimski.html`. Remove one slash. But I don't know whether this is enough to solve the issue.

Comment: Can you open http://10.0.6.179:5656/WEB_NKR/ndvi_shape_files/agro_priishimski/2018-08-07_agro_priishimski.html in your browser? If yes, remove the one slash.